# Are the constrained optimization problem equal to the unconstrained one?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

(1)
\begin{equation}\label{constrained}  
\begin{array}{cl} 
\arg \min \limits_{x} & \|Ax-b\|_2\\
    \mathrm{s.t.} & \|x\|_1\le \epsilon
\end{array}
\end{equation}

(2)
\begin{equation}\label{unconstrained}
\begin{array}{cl}
    \arg \min \limits_{x} & \|x\|_1+\lambda\|Ax-b\|_2
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier.
Are the two optimization problems equal? If so, how to prove this?

Comment: The standard way for obtaining this equivalence is via Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: There are multiple duplicates of this problem. Please select the convex-optimization tag and just scroll down...  alas they don't necessarily have answers, but there is decent discussion in comments.