# Can the constrained optimization problem (1) be transformed into the unconstrained form (2)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

(1)
\begin{equation}\label{constrained}  
\begin{array}{cl} 
\arg \min \limits_{\mathcal{C}_k} & \text{rank}(\mathcal{C}_k)\\
    \mathrm{s.t.} & \mathcal{E}(\phi_{j}^{k})\le \epsilon
\end{array}
\end{equation}

(2)
\begin{equation}\label{unconstrained}
\begin{array}{cl}
    \arg \min \limits_{\mathcal{C}_k} & \mathcal{E}(\phi_{j}^{k})+\lambda \text{rank}(\mathcal{C}_k)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier.
As we know, the Lagrange multiplier method can transform an optimization problem with equality constraints into a unconstrained optimization problem. But, the problem (1) is an optimization problem with inequality constraints.

Comment: What is $\mathcal E$ ?

Comment: Is this really sufficiently different from [the other question you posted](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730548/are-the-constrained-optimization-problem-equal-to-the-unconstrained-one) to warrant a separate post? Sure, the functions are different, but nothing has changed conceptually.

Comment: And of course, neither of these problems is convex.